# Comparing the arrays result result in a true variable even the values are not the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer, 2d

I want to crate a minigame based on guess the order of the flickering buttons. First I add in a vector the flickering buttons order and the I add the user taps on buttons in another array. In the end if the vector values are equal user win the game. The problem is at the end no matter what values are in vectors, there will be a win anyway. I can't find the problem. Here is my whole script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] buttons;
    private string[] culori = new string[3];
    private int[] culoriINT = new int[3];
    private string[] culoriComparare = new string[3];
    private int[] culoriComparareINT = new int[3];
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int indexCourt = 0;
    private bool win = false;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ChangeColors2());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("INT vector[" + i + "]: " + culoriINT[i]);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < culoriComparareINT.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Al doilea vector[" + i + "]: " + culoriComparareINT[i]);
            }
        }
        
    }


    IEnumerator ChangeColors2() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons.Length; j++) { 
            if (index < 10)
            {
                var a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, buttons.Length);
                buttons[a].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
                
                var introducere = buttons[a].GetComponent<IndexButtons>().index;
                culoriINT[index] = introducere;
                index++;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); 
                buttons[a].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("index depasit");
            }
          
            Debug.Log("verde");
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            indexCourt++;
        }
    }

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        index2++;
    }
    public void numePeClick()
    {
        string a = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
        culoriComparareINT[index2] = Convert.ToInt32(a);
        culoriComparare[index2] = a;
        Debug.Log("Cuvant adaugat");
    }

    public void CheckWin()
    {
        
        for (var i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
        {
            if (culoriINT[i] != culoriComparareINT[i])
            {
                win = false;
            }
            else
            {
                win = true;
            }
                
        }

        if (win == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ai pierdut!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Ai castigat!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the for-loop of `CheckWin`, you are not keeping the value `win = false`. At the next iteration it might be set to `true` again. So, the end result depends only on the last element in the array.

You must exit the loop as soon as a non-matching entry is found. You can do so with the `break` statement.

```cs
public void CheckWin()
{
    win = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
    {
        if (culoriINT[i] != culoriComparareINT[i])
        {
            win = false;
            break; // Exit the loop, the arrays are not equal.
        }
    }

    if (win)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ai castigat!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Ai pierdut!");
    }
}
```

This solution would also work if the `break` was not there, as `win` keeps its value `false` once it has been set. However, there is no point in testing the rest of the array at this point, as the inequality of the arrays is already given when one element is unequal.

I also inverted the if-statement at the end of the method. Code is usually more understandable if a condition asks a positive question and the if-part handles the positive outcome and the else the negative one.

Also, you can test a Boolean variable with `if(win)` or `if(!win)` instead of `if(win == true)` or `if(win == false)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advices but even with this modifications I still get the wrong condition, the winning one even if values are not the same.

Comment: Then [debug your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) and see what happens in detail. What do the arrays contain? Do they contain the expected values? Probably there is an error somewhere else. I did not check the whole code.

Comment: I have two for loops in update which show me the content of the arrays. Instead of getting only 3 results per array I get 6 prints. First 3 of them contain the values and the rest are empty. Anyway, there are the same values inside of the arrays on first 3 sockets but I still get the true value if they are different values.

Answer (score 0):

Your CheckWin method will always return only the value of the last comparison. Change to

```
public void CheckWin()
{
    win = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
    {
        win &= culoriINT[i] == culoriComparareINT[i];
    }

    if (win == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ai pierdut!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Ai castigat!");
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still get the winning condition even if the values are not the same.